# Check if Table exists in Predicate Filter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-level-security

I have written a security policy which contains a predicate filter to apply row level security in SQL Server. But, I want to apply the filter predicate only if the table exists in the database. Can anyone please suggest anyway I can to it? Below is the security policy:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('s.policyName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP SECURITY POLICY s.policyName
END
GO  
    CREATE SECURITY POLICY s.policyName 
    ADD  FILTER PREDICATE s.policyName(ColA) ON TableA
    WITH (STATE = ON)       
GO
```

I did try adding an `if` condition before and after the Filter predicate, but its not working. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: You need to use dynamic SQL that is only executed when the table exists. Otherwise, when the statements are parsed and bound to objects, there is an error as binding to an nonexistent object isn't possible.

Comment: You can use `If (exists(select object_id from sys.security_policies where name = 'policyName'))` for check existing security police by name.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just want to make sure the table (and column!) exists before *creating* the policy, rather than making the policy check for the table every time? I don't know that you can drop a table that has a policy associated with it (you certainly can't if the policy function, which has to be schema-bound, references the table), but I think if people can drop tables after the policy is created there is a bigger issue.

```
IF EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    WHERE t.name = N'TableA'
      -- AND t.[schema_id] = SCHEMA_ID(N's') -- 'dbo', 'other' ???
    AND c.name = N'ColA'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE SECURITY POLICY s.policyName 
    ADD  FILTER PREDICATE s.policyFunctionName(ColA) ON TableA
    WITH (STATE = ON);
END
```

And of course you can't create the policy in the first place if the table doesn't exist. It will fail with:

> Msg 33268, Level 16, State 1
>
> Cannot find the object "TableA" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.

So you can use the `IF EXISTS` for nice behavior (you could put a friendly error message in an `ELSE`) or you could just wrap in `TRY/CATCH` and hope for the best.

You might also want to make sure that the function `s.policyFunctionName` exists for a similar reason (and of course you can't call the policy the same as the function), or just let it fail.

Answer (score 0):

SQL checks if the table exists, true the result is 1, if the table does not exist the result is zero. For Example:

```
IF EXISTS ( USE TableA
            SELECT 1 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_TYPE='VIEW' 
            AND TABLE_NAME='TableA') 
   SELECT 1 AS res ELSE SELECT 0 AS res;
  
IF OBJECT_ID ('TableA.s.policyName') IS NOT NULL 
   SELECT 1 AS res ELSE SELECT 0 AS res;
```